# Finding a basic in subspace in vectors space $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In vectors space $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$ we got subspace:

$U =$ { p $\in$  $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$; p(1) = p'(1)} 
and

$V =$ {p $\in$ $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$; p(1) =
$ \int_0^1 p(t)\,dt. $}

How can i find basis of subspace U, V and U $\cap$ V?
How could i start?

Comment: $\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt$ or $\int_0^1 p(t)\,dt$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this, is this correct?

$$p(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$$

$$p'(x)=b+2cx+3dx^2$$

$$\int_0^1 p(t)=ax \Bigg|_0^1 + \frac{bx^2}{2} \Bigg|_0^1+\frac{cx^3}{3} \Bigg|_0^1+\frac{dx^4}{4}\Bigg|_0^1 = a+\frac{b}{2}+\frac{c}{3}+\frac{d}{4}$$

---

$U:$

$$p(1)=p'(1)$$
$$a+b+c+d = b+2c+3d$$
$$a-c-2d=0$$

$ \left\{ \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 \\
0 \\
-1 \\
-2 \\
\end{array}\right] \right\}$

---

$V:$

$$p(1)=\int_0^1 p(t)$$
$$a+b+c+d = a+\frac{b}{2}+\frac{c}{3}+\frac{d}{4}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}b +\frac{2}{3}c +\frac{3}{4}d =0 / \cdot 12$$
$$6b+8c+9d=0$$

$ \left\{ \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 \\
6 \\
8 \\
9 \\
\end{array}\right] \right\}$

---

$U \cap V:$

$$p(1)=\int_0^1 p(t)=p'(1)$$
$$6b+8c+9d=0$$
$$a-c-2d=0$$
$$a+6b+7c+7d=0$$

$ \left\{ \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 \\
6 \\
7 \\
7 \\
\end{array}\right] \right\}$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Write a polynomial $p(t)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$.

Now compute $p(1)$, $p^\prime(1)$ and $\int_0^1p(t)\,dt$ all in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

Equating some of these quantities gives equations in $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ which, if linear, define linear subspaces of $\Bbb R_3[x]$.

Once you have the subspaces descrbed by equations, finding bases should be routine.